# Can't use rhc after installation , for openshift

Tags: rubygems, openshift, vmc, openshift-client-tools

I'm running into a weird issue after installing rhc and vmc.
None of the below seems to be working.

For Openshift:
https://openshift.redhat.com/app/getting_started

For Cloudfoundry:
http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/installing-vmc.html

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

```
root@bose-Vostro-1540:/home/bose# gem install rhc
Successfully installed parseconfig-0.5.2
Successfully installed rhc-0.88.9
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for parseconfig-0.5.2...
Installing ri documentation for rhc-0.88.9...
Installing RDoc documentation for parseconfig-0.5.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rhc-0.88.9...
root@bose-Vostro-1540:/home/bose# rhc
No command 'rhc' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rtc' from package 'nvram-wakeup' (universe)
 Command 'rc' from package 'rc' (universe)
 Command 'rec' from package 'sox' (universe)
 Command 'rcc' from package 'libqt4-dev' (main)
 Command 'rsc' from package 'radare-common' (universe)
 Command 'rvc' from package 'vtgrab' (universe)
rhc: command not found
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar issue has been addressed [here](https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/forums/express/rhc-create-domain-command-not-found). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using `rbenv`, and got the same problem

use `gem list` to check whether it's installed, if so,
maybe you just need find it and add it to your `PATH`.

like I do this

```
ln -s /home/fengyl/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.4.8/bin/rhc /home/fengyl/.rbenv/shims/
```

Comment: What is my 'PATH'?

Answer (score 5):

Try not installing it with sudo.

> gem install rhc

worked for me,

> sudo gem install rhc

did not. The docs ask you to do the former.

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the OpenShift developers working on the client tools and using RVM to test my versions locally with no issues.

If you are using RVM, your $PATH should include something like this (I am using 1.9.3 with a gemset for my client-tools).

```
$ echo $PATH | tr : \\n 
/home/fotios/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@client-tools/bin
/home/fotios/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin
/home/fotios/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin
/home/fotios/.rvm/bin
...

$ which rhc
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@client-tools/bin/rhc
```

If not, there may be a problem with your .bashrc/.profile. Check out the [RVM installation notes](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) or run `rvm notes` to ensure everything is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me right now, none of the current answers solve it.

Here's how I fixed the problem (add ruby gems to your path):

```
PATH="`ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir'`/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution.