# rhc setup - command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, command-line, openshift

I am working on a MacBook Air, OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

After successfully installing

- Ruby 4.1.6 and
- Git 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
- OpenShift client tools `rhc-1.30.2.gem`

I got this message:

> If this is your first time installing the RHC tools, please run 'rhc setup'

But, when I run `rhc setup`(according the the OpenShift documentation) I just get this back:

```
Olivers-MacBook-Air-4:~ oliverhowells$ rhc setup
-bash: $: command not found
```

I want to set up an SSH key, but as long as I get this error, I am not sure how to launch the OpenShift wizard and move forward.

Here is a link to the documentation I am looking at from OpenShift:
https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html

Do you have any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HomeBrew -bash: $: command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222235/homebrew-bash-command-not-found)

Comment: Take a look at [these question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111020/cant-use-rhc-after-installation-for-openshift).

Comment: @HolgerJust I'd argue that duplicate flag isn't the most relevant (given OP is also trying the command correctly).

Comment: After the most recent edit (#5), the error message doesn't match the command you entered. Please post exact and full error messages!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after installing using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). I fixed it by running `rbenv rehash` from the command line.