# Can't install or run OpenShift RHC client tools on MAC OS X

Tags: ruby, git, macos, openshift

I'm trying to install and configure the OpenShift Client tools, in order to be able to install and run a WAR app.

I have been trying to follow [rhc setup - command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222885/rhc-setup-command-not-found) instructions but without success.

The point is that when I run `gem install rhc-1.38.4.gem` it fails because of permissions...

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

So I try to go with **sudo**: `sudo gem install rhc-1.38.4.gem`, and provide the pwd. Everything seems to be correct then...

```
===========================================================================

If this is your first time installing the RHC tools, please run 'rhc setup'

===========================================================================
Successfully installed rhc-1.38.4
Parsing documentation for rhc-1.38.4
Done installing documentation for rhc after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

However, `rhc` command give me the nightmare `-bash: rhc: command not found` error.

Then, I browse to the provided folder, in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/rhc-1.38.4/`, and there you can find all the rhc stuff as it was supposed to be:

```
COPYRIGHT   README.md   autocomplete    conf        lib
LICENSE     Rakefile    bin             features    spec
```

If I get into the bin folder, there is the rhc, but if I try to run it, I get the same error.

My git versión is `2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)`

Ruby is `ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`

Run on OS X 10.11.1

Sorry if I seem too rookie for this, but I have tried to run `sh rhc`, with this result:

```
rhc: line 2: require: command not found
rhc: line 4: def: command not found
rhc: line 5: ARGV.shift: command not found
rhc: line 6: args: command not found
rhc: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `/\s/'
rhc: line 8: `    if ( a.to_s.strip.length == 0 || a.to_s.strip.match(/\s/) ); a = "'#{a}'" end'
```

As far as I understand, it's not a problem with the PATH, as reads this [article](https://forums.openshift.com/rhc-create-domain-command-not-found).

I'm trying to follow the installation steps on [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-osx.html#client-tools).

It will be much appreciated any help, plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `-bash: rhc: command not found` is probably because you installed with `sudo` but you aren't running it as root. So you can try running it `sudo rhc`.

But if that works and you don't want to use `sudo` every time you have to run `rhc` you could fix the permissions on your gem directory so your user has access to write to it. In this case that directory is `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/`. You can either open up the permissions on the directory with `sudo chmod -R 777 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/`, or you could try to `chown` it to your user `sudo chown /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/`.

Alternatively, a less invasive solution would be to [change your gem installation location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619731/1241782) to something local to your user, such as `~/.gem`. This is probably something you should do anyway so that your local Ruby/gem environment doesn't conflict with system Ruby.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mike. This worked and I'll give it a try to your suggestion with the permissions stuff. 
Thanks!